# .Net Configuration: How to use tag values instead of attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration

I'm writing a custom configuration section.  I'd like the xml to look something like this:

```
<MainSettings>
    <UpperCase>True</UpperCase>
    <PopupClient>False</PopupClient>
    <Language>en-GB</Language>
</MainSettings>
```

How do I code the ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationElement derived classes to produce this?

I know how to produce it in this form:

```
<MainSettings>
    <UpperCase value="True" />
    <PopupClient value="False" />
    <Language value="en-GB" />    
<MainSettings>
```

However, this would produce somewhat unpleasant to use model code in the form:

```
mainSettings.UpperCase.Value = true;
```

instead of simply:

```
mainSettings.UpperCase = true;
```

I'm also aware of the xml form:

```
<MainSettings UpperCase="True"
              PopupClient="False"
              Language="en-GB" />
```

which can be married up to the second code form.

So, is it possible to match up the first or second xml forms with the second code form?